# AWS API Gateway multi-tenant API mapping based on user login issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

**Objective:** enable a multi-tenant single website (hosted via s3) to talk to a single API gateway that maps to existing N number of EC2 instances hosting the same API based on the User that is logged in.

**Attempt:**

[Cloud diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6DKm.png)

**Question:** How do I map/route an API request to its respective EC2 APIs based on the user logged in? is it possible to have one HTTP api endpoint that maps to multiple EC2 APIs and some sort of lambda authorizers or AWS Cognito users? that checks the user logged in and returns the response of the API?

Comment: I would guess you simply need to have a regular lambda in there as a dispatcher, that lambda is configured as "lambda proxy" and does whatever it needs to, then it calls the right ec2 instance!?

Comment: @luk2302 that's what I was thinking, it was just proxy to the service needed after its verified the aws cognito user resource ?

Comment: I do not think there is much to *verify*, wether or not the user is allowed to access the api gateway / any service was already decided. You simply need to extract the current user and based on some logic choose the instance to delegate to.

Comment: 1. how many tenants you have, 2. how do you identify a particular user belong to a particular tenant 3. what is the authentication server for these users, is it a common 1 server or each tenant has its own authentication server?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala 1. I have around 50+ ec2 instances which are monolith applications that house its own authentication using apache. 2. since the ec2 instance is a monolith, we just use apache authentication 3. apache

Comment: if a user logs in, how do we know which server to redirect to?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala current architecture is everyone has their own EC2 instance, thus they have their own URL they can access.

Comment: then how about different path prefix in api gateway with http proxy ? /tenant1, /tenant2, /tenant3 etc pointing to its own http backend? like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html)

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I was hoping to have 1 URL in the UI, taking the approach of renaming the path prefix would not work because I would have to know which path I am calling right? The UI does not have that context and was hoping to use api gateway + cognito to do this proper routing